# Swift: strikethroughStyle For Label (Middle Delete Line For Label)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, strikethrough

How to add strikethroughStyle for label. A middle delete line to a number in UILabel. Check the attach image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "strikethrough"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attributeString

Screenshot

[image]

Code

```
NSDictionary * attribtues = @{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                              NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
NSAttributedString * attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"label" attributes:attribtues];
self.label.attributedText = attr;
```

Comment: Can do that in storyboard ?

Comment: Do you have a static text label? I just drag a outlet,then setup in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: You can't do it in storyborad
you have to do it via code

Answer (score 3):

Updated function from @krunal answer for Swift4

```
extension String {
    func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
        return attributeString
    }
}
```

and to call the function is the same

```
yourLabel.attributedText = "yourString".strikeThrough()
```

Answer (score 1):

For Programatically Use Below Code

Prefer to Use Extension:

```
extension String {
    func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
        return attributeString
    }
}
```

And call this Function

```
myLabel.attributedText = "my string".strikeThrough()
```

And Result look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If wanting to use a UILabel extension

```
extension UILabel {
  func strikeThroughText() {
    let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
    self.attributedText = attributeString
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**add middle delete line for UILabel in storyboard**

1. tap uilabel in storyboard, look at utilities. Select `Attributed`

   [image: utilities]
2. tap font icon, open font panel.

   [image: font panel]
3. Select the text you want to change
4. Select middle line (ex: Single)
5. completed.

   [image: result]

Comment: not working in my label where response come from the api

Comment: response come from the api should set programmatically (Leo's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
         let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
         attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
         return attributeString
} }
```

Then in 'viewDidLoad' View Controller

```
yourLabel.attributedText = "yourString".strikeThrough()
```